# Не работает fetch_message() в on_raw_reaction_add Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я делаю функцию в Discord боте на discord.py которая печатает в консоль "Emoji activated" когда пользователь нажимает на определенный эмоджи к сообщению.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    channel = bot.get_channel(810882194159042590)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(842363832344379393)
    reaction = discord.utils.get(message.reactions, emoji='✅')

    if payload.member.id == bot.user.id:
        return

    if payload.message == 842363832344379393 and reaction.emoji == '✅':
        await print("Emoji activated ")
```

Но когда я его запускаю происходит ошибка: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'`.
Я не понимаю что означает эта ошибка, так как переменная с каналом `channel` уже существует.
Что она значит, и как ее можно решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых вы не смогли получить канал(скорее всего, ошиблись циферками), поэтому он принял значения NoneType и по итогу получилась ошибка. К тому же, это действие для вас лишние.

Получить ид сообщения куда поставилась реакцию, можно с помощью -**payload.message_id**

Скопировать эмодзи с дискорда можно с помощью \ :emojiname: (без пробела) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

await print() у вас так же вызовет ошибку.

Код ниже.

```
@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(messages):
    
    user_id = messages.user_id # ID пользователя, который добавил реакцию

    message_id = messages.message_id
    if messages.user_id == bot.user.id:
        return
    
    if message_id == 838114130397233173: # сюда вводим свой ид сообщения
        if messages.emoji.name == "✅": # имя реакции. узнать его можно скопировав с дса. Можно через and
            print("emoji active")
```